# What is a no-op class?

Tags: c#, abstract

I just learned about the Template Method pattern in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2945147/make-sure-base-method-gets-called-in-c/2945171#2945171) to a question about ensuring that methods in base classes are always called by child classes.

Part of the answer talks about base classes vs no-op classes:

> (The decision about whether to make it
>   a no-op or abstract is usually fairly
>   obvious - does the base class make
>   sense on its own, as a concrete
>   class?)

What is a no-op class?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

It isn't the *class* that is no-op, but the implementation of the method.

The answer debates the decision of making the method in the base class abstract (thereby *forcing* derived classes to implement it, even if they want to have it do absolutely nothing) versus implementing it as a "no-op" (i.e. with an empty method body).

If doing nothing is a sensible default, then the base class might implement this method as a no-op so that derived classes are bothered to override only if they actually want something different to happen.

If doing nothing is not sensible, then it makes sense for the method to be abstract.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan: Correction: a class with *at least one* abstract method. But I don't think discussing abstract classes is relevant to this specific question, as it's clearly about methods.

Comment: OK, I didn't read the link, I was just commenting on your answer out of context.

Comment: Appreciate the explanation of why I would use an abstract method over a no-op method. Thanks!

Comment: @ranomore: An abstract method should be used in cases where any legitimate child class must supply a method which is different from any other.  For example, an abstract `Shape` class might include a `GetTypeCode` property which every derivative of `Shape` is supposed to define to return a different number [allowing a sequence of shapes to be serialized into a sequence records each consisting of a type number and a sequence of parameters, and later reconstituted back into a sequence of shapes].  If every concrete type of shape is supposed to return a different value...

Comment: @ranomore: ...then there could be at most one type which didn't override any default implementation the property might have.  Better to have no default than a useless one.  Note that it might be conceptually useful to have a concrete type include a method which was both implemented and abstract, with the implementation being usable only by instances of the base type, but I know of no way to declare such a thing in Java or .NET.

Comment: Does this break the Liskov Substitution principle?

Answer (score 7):

`no-op` is short for `no-operation`, that is, a method that does nothing:

```
public void MyNoOp()
{
}
```

Or from the linked question:

```
public override void Update()
{
    //no-op, does nothing
}
```

Comment: Does this break the Liskov Substitution principle?

Comment: Does it? How would it?